# Why would IP masquerading fix problematic WebRTC connection?

Tags: webrtc, iptables, nat, stun, turn

I'm working with a WebRTC stack that consists of a (firewall-enabled) embedded Linux device, an iOS mobile app, and self-maintained signaling, STUN, and TURN servers.

In 99% of network configurations, the setup works just fine. However, when the embedded Linux device is connected to a [Verizon Jetpack](https://www.verizonwireless.com/support/jetpack-4g-lte-mobile-hotspot-mifi-4620l/) (4G LTE), the device cannot establish a WebRTC connection with the mobile app (regardless of whether the mobile phone is connected to the Jetpack or some other network).

In an effort to debug, I took down the entire firewall on both IPv4 and IPv6, but it made no difference.

Then, I kind of randomly discovered that if I add a masquerading post-routing IPv4 rule to the device's NAT table, it starts working! Specifically, this is the `iptables` command that I used:

```
$ sudo iptables -t nat -A POSTROUTING -o wlan0 -j MASQUERADE
```

Why would this rule get the WebRTC connection working? And is there a more proper way to achieve the same result? The rule above seems too liberal.

Answer (score 1):

I found this question because I was also experiencing a WebRTC ICE timeout when trying to connect to a device on the Jetpack's network. I don't know anything about `iptables` or firewall/DNS/NAT configurations, but your discovery gave me a clue that it must be some settings in the MiFi itself.

Looking at http://my.jetpack (the Jetpacks web config page/app/thing) I discovered a setting that was labelled something like "Enable passthrough VPN" and it was defaulted to true/on. Toggling that to false/off appears to have fixed the connection issue for me.

I'm not 100% sure this is the "real" issue since it seems like two devices on the same VPN should be able to connect. Hopefully it gives you a little bit of a clue in your own search.

Comment: Thanks for posting @mysterycommand ! I had given up on this, but I'll see if I can dig out that Jetpack and give this a shot. I'll let you know.